PROGRESS 4GL - Is it possible to check table fields affecting during assignment?
I have a custom table which has no trigger events for write. I could sense some of the data often modified from particular fields but not sure what is the exact fields in table. Is there way to track or check the table fields affecting during assignment? I understand protop can give us some info but I would like to have a small query which helps to identify fields. Thanks in advance

What do you mean by "I could sense" and "what is the exact fields in table"? And what are you trying to "track or check"? Getting a list of fields that exist in a table is trivial. Figuring out what fields are being accessed or updated for CRUD operations at runtime is not. Especially if you want to somehow do that without modifying the application code. There is no VST that will tell you what fields are being accessed or updated.  The only way that you can find out that information is to add code to trace the execution of your programs.

Bascome - In short, If I do assignment to a field in a table. How do we trace?

If you want to know that in real time, add some code to your program to log the fact that you updated a field. If you are doing a static analysis of your code to see where you might update a field you can generate an XREF with the compiler.

You could also enable auditing to determine that an update occurred but that will not tell you what code made the update unless you also include "application context" events -- and that gets back to you writing some code to enable the desired level of tracing.

Try looking at OpenEdge CDC. It can track changes you make to your databases.
